# Black screen with REGION_VIOLATION while trying to install Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a computer with Windows 7 already installed. I'm using a rufus USB pendrive, and freed up 100Gb on a 1TB hard drive to install it.

I managed to boot correctly and got the purple screen with an icon of a keyboard and a stick figure, then immediately it turns black and I get the following screen:

[image]

I tried pressing enter and I heard a sound effect, and then I could hear more sound effects while pressing the arrow keys, so I assume I'm navigating through some options I cannot see.

Comment: try adding `nomodeset` to the boot parameter of the grub menu

Comment: I don't think I have access to a grub menu.
I just boot the computer, hold a key to access bios settings, and boot the usb from there
And from there I can't input anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video card is causing your problem.

When you see the keyboard/stick figure, hit the <kbd>down arrow</kbd> key. Then <kbd>F6</kbd> and enable `nomodeset`. Then continue with the install.

If that doesn't work for you, if you've got a desktop machine with an onboard video port, reconnect the video monitor to the onboard port, pull the video card, install Ubuntu, and then reconfigure it all back the way it was.

You'll probably have to manually install the correct Nvidia driver for your card.

**Update #1:**

**Boots to Windows. Can't boot Ubuntu. Don't see GRUB menu...** Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and install `boot-repair`. Run it and accept the default repair.

**Update #2:**

**Ubuntu now boots, but crashes...** Disable `secure boot` in your BIOS. Then go to the GRUB menu, and hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key (to edit). Using the arrow keys, find the line that contains "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset". Then hit <kbd>F10</kbd>. Once booted, open `Software & Updates`. Go to the `Additional Drivers` tab. Find the video card and install the proprietary video driver. (If you have Intel processors, then you may also see `intel-microcode`. Enable that too.) Then reboot.

**Update #3:**

User installed a fresh 17.04 (instead of 16.04), then did Updates #1 & #2, and all is well now!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65377/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-trying-to-install-ubuntu-dual-boot).